# How to prevent TextBox history from getting stored in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and there is a textbox for searching.

Is there a way I can flag this `TextBox` so it's text is not stored by Windows or Browser autocomplete features that show a dropdown of all past entries for this `TextBox`?

Comment: It isn't storing in a database or etc. When I click on the textbox  then all searchs which have been before are coming.

Comment: Does your service actually record the inputs to a list, or is this just your browser remembering your previous inputs ? It's more likely just your browser.

Comment: I cleared cache and other cookies etc. But they seem there still,

Comment: @TejasSharma I think Isi's referring to the Windows or Browser feature that will remember what you typed into a TextBox, and show it in a dropdown when the TextBox gets focus, or as you type. Isi, is your WPF application a desktop application or a browser one?

Comment: ah I have not come across that before.

Comment: Browse in InPrivate mode (porn mode) usually stops this from happening ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Undo();//Undoes the last edit operation
textBox.ClearUndo();//Clears information about the most recent operation from the undo buffer
```